# Eclipse not opening project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

The team that I am on is using Eclipse and I need to be able to run project for frontend development. I KNOW NOTHING ABOUT THIS, but eclipse is having an issue after it closes and then when I attempt to re-open it. Here is the log it think...

As I am not the backend developer I have no idea what this all means!

```
!SESSION 2018-02-19 10:07:48.402 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.2.M20171130-0510
java.version=1.8.0_162
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2018-02-19 10:07:58.125
!MESSAGE Warnings while parsing the images from the 'org.eclipse.ui.commandImages' extension point.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2018-02-19 10:07:58.125
!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.eclipse.lsp4e', id='org.eclipse.lsp4e.togglehighlight'

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2018-02-19 10:08:06.407
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2018-02-19 10:08:06.407
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+SHIFT+T:
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.navigate.open.type,Open Type,
        Open a type in a Java editor,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.navigate,Navigate,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@626edbe0,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.lsp4e.symbolinworkspace,Go to Symbol in Workspace,
        ,
        Category(org.eclipse.lsp4e.category,Language Servers,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@213a2fe3,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2018-02-19 10:08:16.989
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\TENDesign'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2018-02-19 10:08:24.172
!MESSAGE While loading class "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer", thread "Thread[Worker-6,5,main]" timed out waiting (5001ms) for thread "Thread[Worker-7,5,main]" to finish starting bundle "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt_1.8.2.20171007-0217 [583]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[Worker-6,5,main]" is proceeding but "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer" may not be fully initialized.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to acquire the state change lock for the module: osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.8.2.20171007-0217"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.m2e.jdt"; singleton:="true" [id=583] STARTED [STARTED]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.lockStateChange(Module.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.computeClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:3595)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:3571)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:3093)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$10.run(JavaModelManager.java:3018)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeAllContainers(JavaModelManager.java:3056)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2056)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:3548)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2986)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:3150)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:2255)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.createExternalArchiveDelta(DeltaProcessor.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.checkExternalArchiveChanges(DeltaProcessor.java:868)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.resourceChanged(DeltaProcessor.java:2071)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessingState.resourceChanged(DeltaProcessingState.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.handleEvent(NotificationManager.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastEvent(Workspace.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.refreshLocal(Resource.java:1559)
    at org.eclipse.rse.internal.files.ui.resources.SystemRemoteEditManager.refreshRemoteEditProject(SystemRemoteEditManager.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.rse.internal.files.ui.Activator$InitRemoteEditJob.run(Activator.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after waiting 5 seconds to acquire the lock.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.lockStateChange(Module.java:334)
    ... 39 more
Root exception:
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after waiting 5 seconds to acquire the lock.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.lockStateChange(Module.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.computeClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:3595)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:3571)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:3093)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$10.run(JavaModelManager.java:3018)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeAllContainers(JavaModelManager.java:3056)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2056)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:3548)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2986)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:3150)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:2255)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.createExternalArchiveDelta(DeltaProcessor.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.checkExternalArchiveChanges(DeltaProcessor.java:868)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.resourceChanged(DeltaProcessor.java:2071)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessingState.resourceChanged(DeltaProcessingState.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.handleEvent(NotificationManager.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastEvent(Workspace.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.refreshLocal(Resource.java:1559)
    at org.eclipse.rse.internal.files.ui.resources.SystemRemoteEditManager.refreshRemoteEditProject(SystemRemoteEditManager.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.rse.internal.files.ui.Activator$InitRemoteEditJob.run(Activator.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.core 2 0 2018-02-19 10:08:57.959
!MESSAGE The Java indexing could not index C:/Users/TENDesign/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/external/asm-all-repackaged/2.5.0-b32/asm-all-repackaged-2.5.0-b32.jar|module-info.class. This .class file doesn't follow the class file format specification. Please report this issue against the .class file vendor

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2018-02-19 10:26:40.945
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2018-02-19 10:26:40.945
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+R:
Binding(CTRL+R,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.RunToLine,Run to Line,
        Resume and break when execution reaches the current line,
        Category(org.eclipse.debug.ui.category.run,Run/Debug,Run/Debug command category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@6e7c0efa,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.debug.ui.debugging,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+R,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.restart.commands.restart,Trigger Restart,
        Restart Spring Boot Application,
        Category(org.eclipse.debug.ui.category.run,Run/Debug,Run/Debug command category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@202411a,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.debug.ui.console,,,system)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface.text 2 0 2018-02-19 10:45:10.896
!MESSAGE Duplicate template id: 'org.eclipse.wst.xslt.templates.xpath.number'

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface.text 2 0 2018-02-19 10:45:10.909
!MESSAGE Duplicate template id: 'org.eclipse.wst.xslt.templates.xpath.round'
```

removing

```
-javaagent:lombok.jar
```

from the configuration file allows it to start.

Comment: I'd reinstall Eclipse.

Comment: it appears removing `-javaagent:lombok.jar` from the config allows it to start

Comment: How did that javaagent get in the config in the first place?

Comment: that's a great question that I will ask the backend developer in the morning. in the mean time at least I know what the issue is.

Comment: Looks like Lombok is something that has to be [formally installed](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse) into your IDE -- just having the library in CLASSPATH isn't enough unless you're just developing on the console. Check Eclipse > About, which will include a line about Lombok if it's installed. It appears that if the project was started with Lombok, you're going to need to continue using it because it provides a lot of syntactic sugar. The alternative is to go back to vanilla Java with some major refactoring.

Comment: @MarsAtomic looking at eclipse>about>installation details>installed software, I am not seeing a reference to Lombok. I thought when we set this up today, we installed it. Possible it didn't fully install?

Comment: I don't think you have to click on Installation Details. If you scroll the About dialog, you should see a line specifying the version of Lombok (if installed, as per the link I previously provided). If it were me, at this point, I'd find a donor machine and do a fresh install of your favored Eclipse variant and try to install Lombok on top of it, import that one project and see how it goes. It's quite possible that some other plugin is interfering with Lombok.